# passing argument to filter not in html template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We can pass arguments to filter in template such as:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | someFilter:var1">
```

for

```
 angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
    .filter('someFilter', function () {
        return function (input, var1) {

            return var1;
        }
     });
```

but how to pass variable when filter is assigned in controller, when i dont have access to internal template of component that i am using. For example `ui-grid` column has `cellFilter` property.

For example I want to pass data from $resource to the filter

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your template :

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | someFilter:var1">
```

You'll have this in your controller :

```
$filter('someFilter')(friend, var1); // $filter('filterName')(filteredValue, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get access to controller scope by using `grid.appScope`

for exmple your cell template is :

`cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'>{{ row.entity.userName | someFilter : grid.appScope.var1}}</div>",`

And in your controller:

```
 $http.get('/url/blablab').success(function(){
    $scope.var1 = "value passed to filter"
 })
```